# Delphi: How to select row in a TDBGrid after deleting a record?

Tags: delphi

I'm running a SQL query to delete the record, then trying the following:

```
gridProjects.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
try
  gridProjects.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
finally
  gridProjects.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
```

The record disappears from the grid, but then the user cannot select another row in the grid, using the mouse or keyboard, and no row in the grid is highlighted.  It acts as if it's locked up.

Comment: Have you tested to see if `DataSet.ControlsDisabled` is false?

Comment: That didn't seem to help.  I did, however, try running this:

ShowMessage(BoolToStr(gridProjects.DataSource.DataSet.ControlsDisabled, True));

And it did select a row in the dbGrid like I want.  Unfortunately, this only seems to work if a ShowMessage call is made.  It won't select the row if the Showmessage call isn't used.

Comment: That's not meant to fix your problem, that's to see if data aware controls are in fact enabled or not. If that 'ShowMessage' displays 'True', that means there's a mismatch of 'Enable/DisableControls' calls in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the call to `DisableControls` to inside the `try/finally` block.  If that "solves" the immediate issue, stop everything and go find out what is throwing an exception in `DisableControls`.